# Vibrator side effects

Tags: sex, sexuality

I'm curious about side effects of vibrators because I see a lot of women, who can't have sex with men in reality. They decide to use vibrators as a solution. So I would like to know is there any side effects for using it? [image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*The literature regarding the use of sex toys in women is sparse.
I have found two studies, which describe potential side effects related to the use of sex toys in women:*

- Transmission of **sexual transmitted disease** due to the use of uncleaned and shared penetrative sex toys
- Higher prevalence of **bacterial vaginosis**
- **Vaginal irritation and trauma** in forceful insertion or when lubricants are not used
- **Allergies of the vaginal mucosa to the sex toy** (depending on the sex toy's type of material)

**Above mentionned side effects can be prevented by thorough cleaning of sex toys (or use of condoms), use of lubricants and selection of the sex toy's material.**

*References:*

Lee R. Health care problems of lesbian, gay, bisexual, and transgender patients. Western Journal of Medicine. 2000;172(6):403-408.

Marrazzo JM, Coffey P, Bingham A. Sexual Practices, Risk Perception and Knowledge Of Sexually Transmitted Disease Risk Among Lesbian and Bisexual Women. Perspectives on sexual and reproductive health. 2005;37(1):6-12. doi:10.1363/psrh.37.006.05.

Comment: Just a note, some condoms may promote same symptoms if it is a latex allergy.

Comment: I'm surprised that research about sex toy can lack interest